# Exiftool's "-tagsfromfile" does not help recover all metadata (#iphone)

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, iphone, metadata, geolocation

This is a long standing practical problem (more than one year). I always want to finish it, but every time I tried I failed. I have consulted several threads for it.

I have a bunch of daily-life videos, and I am making more with my iphone. Before my macbook get filled up with the videos, I'd really want to compress and organize them in a clean and systematic way.

## TL;DR

Object: I want to compress my videos without losing metadata, or at least keeping the minimum amount of metadata **so my iPhone can present the videos with when and where they were taken.**

Obstructions: Exiftool's "-tagsfromfile" does not copy and overwrite the metadata completely. I have even tried some variations: *-all*, *-all:all*, *−overwrite_original* ...

---

## Background

I used ffmpeg to compress and exiftool to re-tag, following

[How can I reduce a video's size with ffmpeg?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28803/how-can-i-reduce-a-videos-size-with-ffmpeg)

> See this answer. Quoted below for convenience:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 output.mp4
> ```

However, compression by ffmpeg kills almost all metadata, so I turned to exiftool by

[Can EXIF data be copied completely from one image to another?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85299/can-exif-data-be-copied-completely-from-one-image-to-another)

> I suggest using the excellent exiftool by Phil Harvey:
>
> ```
> exiftool -TagsFromFile fromImage.jpg toImage.jpg
> ```

---

## Problem

The main problem is while *-TagsFromFile* does copy/overwrite some metadata, it does not do it completely, at least for my videos. I have also tried

```
exiftool −overwrite_original -r -TagsFromFile from.MOV -all to.MOV
```

and some other varieties e.g. replacing *-all* to *-all:all*, but nothing works.

Perhaps the most I care are the tags *-CreationDate* and *-GPS* (see Appendix) because I want to keep track of when and where my photos and videos were taken, and because I want those data to at least be presented in my iPhone.

Here are the previews of the videos *from.MOV* (original) and *to.MOV* (compressed) in my iPhone.

*from.MOV* (location hidden):

[image]

*to.MOV* (no address/location showed!):

[image]

Apparently, something is missing, so after compression the location **cannot be presented.**

---

## Questions

1. What should I do to let my iPhone show where the compressed video's original file was taken?
2. Is there a way to copy and overwrite all metadata? Is it possible to make the metadata identical?
3. Side question: When I was playing around with *exiftool*'s *-TagsFromFile* function, I used it to try to overwrite the metadata of an image to another (both taken by iPhone). However, this case was worse than the videos' case: not only the location was not overwritten, nor the time! Again, I have tried some varieties replacing *-all* to *-all:all*. So is there a way to fix this?

---

## Appendix

In this appendix, I list the date/time and GPS related metadata of the original and compressed videos.

> from.MOV (original):
>
> ```
> File Size                       : 2.9 MB
> File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:05:16 05:50:36-05:00
> File Access Date/Time           : 2018:05:16 07:54:42-05:00
> File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:05:16 07:51:58-05:00
> File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
> File Type                       : MOV
> Create Date                     : 2018:05:16 10:50:36
> Modify Date                     : 2018:05:16 10:50:38
> Track Create Date               : 2018:05:16 10:50:36
> Track Modify Date               : 2018:05:16 10:50:38
> Creation Date                   : 2018:05:16 05:50:36-05:00
> GPS Coordinates                 : xx deg yy' z.zz" N, aa deg bb' c.cc" W, 261.305 m Above Sea Level
> GPS Altitude                    : 261.305 m
> GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
> GPS Latitude                    : xx deg yy' z.zz" N
> GPS Longitude                   : aa deg bb' c.cc" W
> GPS Position                    : xx deg yy' z,zz" N, aa deg bb' c.cc" W
> ```
>
> to.MOV (compressed):
>
> ```
> File Size                       : 194 kB
> File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:05:16 07:54:42-05:00
> File Access Date/Time           : 2018:05:16 07:54:57-05:00
> File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:05:16 07:54:42-05:00
> File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
> File Type                       : MOV
> Creation Date                   : 2018:05:16 05:50:36-05:00
> Track Create Date               : 2018:05:16 10:50:36
> Track Modify Date               : 2018:05:16 10:50:38
> Media Create Date               : 2018:05:16 10:50:36
> Media Modify Date               : 2018:05:16 10:50:38
> Creation Date                   : 2018:05:16 05:50:36-05:00
> Create Date                     : 2018:05:16 10:50:36
> Modify Date                     : 2018:05:16 10:50:38
> GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
> GPS Latitude                    : xx deg yy' z.zz" N
> GPS Longitude                   : aa deg bb' c.cc" W
> GPS Altitude                    : 261.3 m Above Sea Level
> GPS Latitude Ref                : North
> GPS Longitude Ref               : West
> GPS Position                    : xx deg yy' z.zz" N, aa deg bb' c.cc" W
> ```
>
> (I have changed the location into xyzabc just for privacy :P)

As you can see, not only are the date/time slightly different, but there even are more redundant new tags. Probably the thing that concerns me the most is that the tag *-GPS Coordinates* is not copied from *from.MOV* to *to.MOV*. Though the essential information has been copied, I guess that might be the reason why my iphone does not show its location. Thus this leads to my second question (above).

---

Comment: Unfortunately no answer, but it seems to be related/identical as this bug: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4209 I'm also looking for the solution to this. It could be a namespace / naming issue of the metadata in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but a work-around using https://www.bento4.com from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6193#comment:6

```
ffmpeg -i source.mov converted.mp4
mp4extract moov/meta source.mov source-metadata
mp4edit --insert moov:source-metadata converted.mp4 converted-withmeta.mp4
```

hope this helps!